# Why would this function return a row that ended=1?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My function:

```
function fetchAllGames($limit=9, $page=1, $isEnded="")
{
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;

    if($isEnded!=""){$myWhere="WHERE ended=".$isEnded." ";}else{$myWhere="";}
    $offset=($page - 1) * $limit;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        created_timestamp,
        end_timestamp,
        winner_userid,
        ended,
        name,
        game_uniqID,
        game_id,
        img
        FROM ".$db_table_prefix."game 
        ".$myWhere."
        LIMIT ".$limit." 
        OFFSET ".$offset);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($created_timestamp, $end_timestamp, $winner_userid, $ended, $name, $game_uniqID, $game_id, $gameImg);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $row[] = array('created_timestamp' => $created_timestamp, 'end_timestamp' => $end_timestamp, 'winner_userid' => $winner_userid, 'ended' => $ended, 'name' => $name, 'game_uniqID' => $game_uniqID, 'game_id' => $game_id, 'gameImg' => $gameImg);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    if (isset($row)){
        return ($row);
    }
}
```

If I call it by `$allGames = fetchAllGames(9,1,0);` then it returns both rows with ended=0 and a row that ended=1, and if I call it by `$allGames = fetchAllGames(9,1,1);` it returns just rows with ended=1. I cant figure out why either. Am I missing something?

Comment: because 0="" after the cast, and it picks up the `else{$myWhere="";}`

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit?

Comment: Not logically, no. But it appears to be the case in your code. Can you vardump `$myWhere` if you pass 0?

Comment: I figured it out (answer below). Still not sure why it was doing that.

Answer (score -1):

Still not sure why it's doing that, but I just fixed it by changing the if to:

```
    $myWhere = "";
    if($isEnded=="active"){$myWhere="WHERE ended=0";}elseif($isEnded=="ended"){$myWhere="WHERE ended=1";}
```

And calling it by

```
$allGames = fetchAllGames(9,1,"active");
```

Or

```
$allGames = fetchAllGames(9,1,"ended");
```

Or leaving it empty for all of them.